# How to get mapping records as comma separated values in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get mapping table data as comma separated in laravel eloquent.

In controller I have list function

```
public function list(Request $request){
    
    // $data = Application::all();
    $pagelimit = $request->pagelimit ?? 10;
    $data = Application::search(($request->input('query')?$request->input('query'):''))->with('technology.technologyInfo');
    if($request->status === 'ACTIVE')
            $data = $data->where('status', 'ACTIVE');
            $data = $data->orderBy('id','desc');
    if(!$request->pagelimit)
            $data = $data->get();
    else
        $data = $data->paginate($pagelimit);

    return $this->json_response('success', 'data fetched', $data);
}
```

then in application model (Application)

```
public function technology()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ApplicationTechnology', 'application_id', 'id');
    }
```

then in mapping model (ApplicationTechnology)

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ApplicationTechnology extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'application_technology';

    public function technologyInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Technology', 'id','technology_id');
    }
}
```

The above coding gives result with mapping data(technology_info) in new row,But I want this column as comma separated **Like 'technology_info' : {'PHP', 'JAVA', 'Python'}**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try `pluck()` and `join()`
`

#### in ApplicationTechnology.php

```php
protected $appends = ['technology_info_with_comma']; //https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json


public function getTechnologyInfoWithCommaAttribute()
{
    return $this->technologyInfo()->pluck('name')->join(',');
}
```

ref link

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting the below error when trying your code

Error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string in file C:\xampp2\htdocs\ocr\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 587

Comment: still same error, I updated with() as like

->with('technology.technologyInfoWithComma');

Comment: yes, added that function in ApplicationTechnology model

Comment: If I remove this part of code its working,
->pluck('name')->join(',')

Comment: still same error, if I remove that pluck and join then run

Comment: remove old code and try this new one i have tested this it is working on my side here `with()` will not work  it `$appends`

Comment: not works again. please share what have to present inside with